# Rewriterule to remove .php and .html in .htaccess file messing up my +1 counter, making it +2

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm making a pretty simple website for a friend who wants to be able to create a custom link and track the amount of clicks. I thought it would be simple, so I began and sort of finished it.

Now the problem is that I want a RewriteRule to remove .php and .html from the URL, which I have done using:

```apache
# remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
# remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It was all working fine, but now when I create a link and use it, it adds 2 to the total_visits instead of 1.

The full code for every link getting made:

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    require "PHPH/connect.php";

    $fullurl = 'https://www.example.com/example/';

    $sql = "UPDATE links SET total_visits = total_visits + 1 WHERE link_url = :fullurl"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fullurl", $fullurl);
    $stmt->execute();

    header("Location: https://www.example.com/example/");
    exit();
?>
```

I personally think it's because of the RewriteRules because there is nothing else interfering with my code, and when I remove the RewriteRules, everything works fine, and it adds +1, which is the goal.

My database total_visits is just an empty int without any auto increments.

Any suggestions would help :)

- Removing RewriteRules: worked
- Clearing cache, cookies, and using incognito browser: did not work
- Changing database and database server: did not work
- Asking ChatGPT: did nothing
- Asking my school teacher who teaches PHP and SQL: didn't want to spend time on it because it was not for school

Comment: What is the actual URL you are requesting/linking to? Do you have any other rules in the `.htaccess` file? Those rules don't actually "remove" `.php` or `.html` - they add it back, allowing URLs without the file extension to work.

Comment: @MrWhite the actual website in question is zipzoom.nl (it’s password protected) and as endgoal I tried using YouTube, google and instagram and all adding 2 per visit. I have noticed that it works on my iPhone but not on my pc… also other rules in my .htaccess are simple error pages, ‘Options All -Indexes‘ and ‘’’RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]’’’

Comment: "the actual website in question is example.com" - I meant the URL-path. What is the format of the URL being requested? (eg. `/example`, `/example/`, `/example.html`, `/foo/example`, etc.?) And what file(s) should these requests map to? I'm trying to ascertain how/if these rules should be processed. eg. a request for the root directory (ie. homepage) is not processed by these rules. If you are making a request for `/example/` (_with_ a trailing slash, as used in your PHP code) then these rules are wrong.

Comment: "it works on my iPhone but not on my pc" - These are server-side directives, so there should be no difference between devices in this respect. The only thing that could affect different devices is caching and the intermediary network.

Comment: _Aside:_ Why do you have two file extensions, `.php` and `.html`?

Comment: Ohh the the url path is example.nl/example.php (in this case without the .php) the links are being created in the root of the server. The reason for .php and .html is because the website itself is written in php but the error pages are in html. I’m new to php and the whole .htaccess so sorry if some things are confusing haha